# Installing pip on QNAP

Tags: python, command-line, pip, qnap

It looks like Python 2.7.5+ don't support pip anymore.  I'm wondering if there are other ways to get pip working as I can't get it to install anything as each time I try, I get the error saying:

> pip: command not found

I can't even install pip anymore.  I'm running into applications that tell me to use pip but I can't get pip as a command.

Comment: can't you use pip3 and work with python 3 instead?

Comment: This is what I get from using pip3:

---

[code] /opt/bin/python3: /opt/lib/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.26 not found (required by /opt/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0)

/opt/bin/python3: /opt/lib/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.27 not found (required by /opt/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0) [/code]

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get pip3 . be sure to run the script with python3 and its recommended to use version 21.0.1 cuz its stable and worked on my qnap ts832-px

```
python3 get-pip.py pip==21.0.1
```

get file from here:
https://github.com/pypa/get-pip